# Handling cases of increased throughput with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I solve a problem in which the number of visits is fixed. The number of visitors at different times may vary, and accordingly it is necessary to anticipate cases when the throughput will increase ...

I googled a lot, looked towards asynchrony in spring boot, but it seems to me this is not my case.

Tell me, how is the bandwidth issue resolved? what should I read more on this topic to solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: You need to define what is the problem. Do you have a specific limited resource? (like memory, CPU, network bandwidth). Depends on it is the answer. Maybe you need Horizontal Scaling

Comment: This was part of the job assignment. I could not complete this part, but now I want to figure out what they wanted to see from me.
The task does not say whether there is any limited resource, I can assume that the load on the channel, but not sure.
My task was to provide for cases of bandwidth changes. Apparently, during the execution of the application, it can change dynamically, and I need to provide for a solution.

The visitor registration record is saved in the database H2 sql.